# SWFLoader - "SWF all over the place"

Tags: apache-flex, flash, components, containers, swfloader

I need to load in an swf component but I want it to be an exact width and height, problem is that when I set width and height it doesn't matter, content of that swf still goes out of predefined bounds. How can I tell it not to do so, so it will work exactly as in html document embed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spend a couple of hours trying to make a workaround and then looked at this website and found a solution in 2 minutes...